# Pulling calender events from Outlook into a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar, outlook-restapi

I am creating a ASP.NET web app using [FullCalender](https://fullcalendar.io/) I've added CRUD functionality in JQuery and now I am trying to add integration with outlook calender to pull the events of a user who logs into their outlook account. I've gone through the [REST API Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial) to set up authentication and display events on a page.

My database Has the name MyDatabaseEntities and contains and Events table which contains the entitys EventID, Subject, Description, Start, End, Themecolor and IsFullDay.

How can I modify the below class so that it inserts the events into my database? This would then allow me to display them on my calender.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Calendar()
    {
        string token = await GetAccessToken();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            // If there's no token in the session, redirect to Home
            return Redirect("/");
        }

        string userEmail = await GetUserEmail();

        GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                    requestMessage.Headers.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", userEmail);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }));

        try
        {
            var eventResults = await client.Me.Events.Request()
                                .OrderBy("start/dateTime DESC")
                                .Select("subject,start,end")
                                .Top(10)
                                .GetAsync();

            return View(eventResults.CurrentPage);
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { message = "ERROR retrieving events", debug = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Comment: "authentification" is not a word. "authentication" is, though. :-)

Comment: Anyway, to insert the stuff into your database, presumably you need to take the `eventResults` object and write some DB code to insert it, using whatever DB library you're using. It's unclear what that task has to do with fullCalendar. It barely even relates to Outlook's API - you can examine the object (doesn't really matter where it comes from, its content is the important thing, but you didn't share that), pick out the properties you need and write the SQL / Linq / whatever to save them to your DB. Have you tried that? Not sure what the issue you're having actually is?

Comment: Also why doesn't the existing code allow you to display the events on your calendar? Other than the likelihood that the data isn't in the format that fullCalendar likes (in which case you could write some code to transform it, just the same as you'll need to in order to save it to the DB), there's nothing to stop you passing through data direct from the Outlook API to fullCalendar, without needing a database. Your overall goal here seems like it needs more thought or clarification.

Comment: Ah sorry If I wasn't clear, I only included the information about full calendar to give perspective on what I was trying to do in the project which is to get the results from the outlook calendar and place them into the view which uses full calendar. I will look into that thanks

Comment: Its not that it doesn't display it, it displays it on a separate page. I just wasn't sure how to get the events into my database so that they can be shown on the calendar.

Comment: a separate page from what? And if it displays it, but on a "separate" page, then surely you just need to move it to the "same" page, whatever you mean by that. It's still unclear why that requires a database record. Maybe I'm missing the point but the logic here seems a little muddled.

Comment: Well because I followed the outlook example it takes the calendar events and displays them on a separate page. I thought that it would need to be a database record so that it can be displayed and edited etc. Maybe I am coming from the wrong angle. Do I not need a database? I just wanted to integrate outlook calendar events into my calendar and have been trying to do that by following the tutorial on the REST API page.

Comment: a database just seems like an unnecessary extra intermediary. The data is already stored in outlook. Why duplicate that? You just need to create a feed of data in JSON, based on your Outlook data, that fullCalendar can understand. Then if you want to save events back to Outlook again, you can hook into fullCalendar's various callback options and run the appropriate code to collect the relevant info and send it back to Outlook (via ajax or whatever).

Comment: Since fullCalendar is entirely client-side, you might be better off using the Javascript API as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial (ignore the bit about a nodeJS server, you can still use an MVC site as the base), but you can make ajax calls direct from the browser to the Graph API. You can hook it into fullCalendar's more flexible event feed option: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ to allow you to transform the data to full-Calendar-friendly format after you download it from Outlook.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies what I need to do.